# Phone line part identification

Tags: wiring, telephone, phone-wiring

I'm trying to determine the name and function of the part in the attached picture. I'm in the process of fixing dead phone jacks in my house and I've come across two of these so far. They look like they're functioning as some kind of junction, but there seems to be a bit more going on in these [than in the ones I've found online](http://www.suttlesolutions.com/catalog/suttle-products/premise-copper-passive-products/jacks-and-wall-plates/connecting-blocks/4term-42a-connect-block-block-only.html). Any ideas?

The numbers on the device are SE 1542 A IND

[image]

Comment: Looks like some sort of RFI suppression device.

Comment: Comintern is correct.  It's been years since I've seen one (eighteen years as tech with AT&T and fifteen as manager).  These were only used when the RF interference was really bad, so you don't want to remove them unless the station creating the interference has gone off the air.  (For weak interference we used a small device that attached to the protector/NID.)  This was an inductive device; the next step up was capacitive.